# Non linear system of differential equations on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, runge-kutta

I'm new on MATLAB, and I was trying for fun to resolve the Friedmann equations using the Runge-Kutta algorithm.

If you don't know it, the Friedmann equations has the following form:

Friedmann equations for expanding universe
[image]

, where the curvature `k` is given by the values `-1, 0 or 1`.

Also, the state equation for the pressure `p` is given by:

State equation for the pressure

[image]

So, I have the Runge-Kutta algorithm:

```
    function [t,x,y] =rk_2_1(f,g,t0,tf,x0,y0,n)
  h=(tf-t0)/n;
  t=t0:h:tf;
  x=zeros(n+1,1); %reserva memoria para n+1 element(i)os del vect(i)or x(i)
  y=zeros(n+1,1);
  x(1)=x0; y(1)=y0;

  for i=1:n
    k1=h*f(t(i),x(i),y(i));
    l1=h*g(t(i),x(i),y(i));
    k2=h*f(t(i)+h/2,x(i)+k1/2,y(i)+l1/2);
    l2=h*g(t(i)+h/2,x(i)+k1/2,y(i)+l1/2);
    k3=h*f(t(i)+h/2,x(i)+k2/2,y(i)+l2/2);
    l3=h*g(t(i)+h/2,x(i)+k2/2,y(i)+l2/2);
    k4=h*f(t(i)+h,x(i)+k3,y(i)+l3);
    l4=h*g(t(i)+h,x(i)+k3,y(i)+l3);

    x(i+1)=x(i)+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
    y(i+1)=y(i)+(l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)/6;        
  end
end
```

, but I have three problems:

1. I don't know how to put symbolically the density `\rho`on my function.
2. I don't know to define the second function `g=@(t,x,y)`, because I have a derivative of a with respect to time.
3. And the last one, what happens with `k=sqrt(-1)`? Because I need that result symbollicaly, but I want the whole result numerically.

Sorry if my questions are basic, but I don't know how to do this and I need some advice or help.

Thank u very much :)

Comment: How do you expect a symbolic function to work in a numerical solution to a set of differential equations? You can use `k=1i`, that will exactly be `i`.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new on this...

Comment: It's OK to be new, but you should always first learn the language you're using (I'm not saying you didn't, just a general remark) and look around the [help]. In particular, look at [ask] a good question. Your question as it stands is unclear.

Comment: So, the main question will be the question number 2: how can I define a function with it's derivative inside?

I have a confussion in how to do that.

Comment: As I said, I don't understand the question.

Comment: OK, sorry. 

Hmmm, so: forget the questions and focus on this: I want to resolve the Friedmann equations using RK algorithm. My problem is that I don't know how to define the below function on the image, because I have a derivative, and I don't know how to write it. For example, if the function has the form 'g=@(t,x,y) a*x-b*y' it's fine for me. But how can I write the below function on the image?

Comment: I can't and won't forget the questions. Stack Overflow is about questions (on-topic ones) and corresponding answers. If you make up your mind about what you ask, and you can formulate it in a clear way, edit your question above to reflect it. Then people have a chance to answer it. Your question should be self-contained as-is, don't ask for people to weed through comments written in tiny letters to figure out what you want. Once you're done editing, you can also delete your obsolete comments.